Unable to Understand How Current Divides in Parallel Circuits
for some context: I was self-studying and got confused about this question. This is a past paper question from the CAIE O Levels Board and its reference code is shown in the image attached below. I don't need help with the actual question, but rather the underlying concept.
My Thinking: As seen in part (b), the brightness of light shown on the LDR decreases, and so its resistance increases. Since resistance adds up in series, the total resistance of branch "A" increases and since current divides in parallel, branch "A" gets less current and branch "B" gets more current. Thus, the reading on ammeter 2 increases.
But apparently, my working is wrong and the correct answer is "The reading on ammeter 2 does not change because voltage across resistor N does not change". Now I get it, using the equation V = IR there would be same voltage across branch "B" and its resistance will not be affected, so its current will be the same.
But then does that mean my concept of current dividing across parallel branches was wrong?


You explicitly expected something else than the correct answer. So you must be wrong. (Yes, the answer key is correct.) Your gut feeling is very reasonable and is a common beginner's misconception.

You have assumed that the reading on ammeter 1 does not change, ie the effective resistance of the whole circuit has not changed.

For ideal zero resistance ammeters: Vn = Vsource at all times SO In = V'R = Vsource/Rn at all times. || Im = V/R = + Vsource / (Rldr + Rm).

Current going through a branch in a circuit divides, with more going to branches of less resistance. This part of your reasoning is correct. What you failed to account for is that the current being divided isn't the same as the LDR's resistance changes. As the resistance increases, the current entering the branched top node (i.e. the current out of the source) decreases. At the same time, the way that current divides between the two branches changes, with the left branch taking a smaller fraction and the right branch taking more. In the right branch, the effects cancel out and the current stays constant.
You could follow my reasoning above with algebra: the combined resistance seen by the source is $$R=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{L+M}+\frac{1}{N}},$$ and the total current in the circuit is $I=V/R$ (where $L$ is the LDR's resistance). The fraction of the current going into the right branch (through ammeter 2) is $$\frac{I_2}{I}=\frac{1/N}{1/R}=\frac{R}{N}.$$ Again, you're perfectly correct that this ratio increases as $L$ increases. But the actual amount of current through the ammeter is still $$I_2=\frac{I_2}{I}\cdot I=\frac{R}{N}\cdot\frac{V}{R}=\frac{V}{N},$$ which doesn't change when $L$ changes.
But notice that you can also see $I_2=V/N$ directly from looking at the circuit diagram. This is much simpler (and faster!) than the above reasoning, where you have to balance two opposing facts about the current ("more of the current goes to the right" vs. "there is less current overall") and see that they cancel out.

I think your underlying misconception (a common one at that) is that you think of voltage sources as current sources.
A voltage source supplies a specific voltage. The current it supplies depends on the resistance of the supplied circuit. A current source supplies a specific current. The voltage it supplies depends on the resistance of the supplied circuit.
Real sources of electricity are neither, but in most cases they are much closer to a voltage source than a current source.
So now apply this to your problem. Assume the power supply is a battery. A battery does not supply a constant current which then has to be divided among the possible paths. It supplies a constant voltage, and additional parallel paths lead to larger currents from the battery. The total current supplied by the battery does have to be divided among the paths, but additional paths increase the total current instead of decreasing the current per path.

Reduced to basics it should be clear. (For some values of should be :-) ).

$V_{\text{source}}$  = input voltage.
$V_{\text{N}}$ = voltage across $\text{N}$.
$V_{\text{M}}$ = voltage across $\text{M}$.
$R_{\text{LDR}}$ = resistance of $\text{LDR}$.

Ohm's Law says: $I = \dfrac{V}{R}$.
So, for ideal zero resistance ammeters:

$V_{\text{N}} = V_{\text{source}}$ at all times,

so

$I_{\text{N}} = V'R = \dfrac{V_{\text{source}}}{R_{\text{N}}}$ at all times

and

$I_{\text{M}} = \dfrac{V}{R} = \dfrac{V_{\text{source}}}{(R_{\text{LDR}} +  R_{\text{M}})}$.

So

$I_{\text{N}}$ is constant as $V_{\text{N}}$ is constant.
$I_{\text{M}}$ varies as $R_{\text{LDR}}$ varies.



My Thinking: As seen in part (b), the brightness of light shown on the
LDR decreases, and so its resistance increases. Since resistance adds
up in series, the total resistance of branch "A" increases and since
current divides in parallel, branch "A" gets less current and branch
"B" gets more current. Thus, the reading on ammeter 2 increases.

Your thinking is not totally wrong. In reality, the internal resistance of the battery tends to drop as the total current going around the circuit drops, and the voltage on the battery terminals increases. This means there would actually be a slight increase in the current foing through ammeter 2. These sort of homework exercises generally assume an idealised battery with no internal resistance and that acts as an ideal voltage source. your intuition is possibly based on real life experience of measuring the voltage of a half dead car battery and noticing the battery voltage drop when putting it under load. In the idealised case, the current through ammeter 2 is assumed to be independent of the flow through the parallel branch.
Another situation where the concept of a divided current flow is not totally wrong is to imagine doubling the voltage of the battery. Doubling the voltage would double the current through each branch and the current would be divided between the two branches in the same ratio as before the the voltage increased.
